# Check if SQL statement returns empty in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to check if my query return a value or not, but I can't make sense of it since the `if-statement` works but not the `else if-statement`.

Basically I want to set a Label to `Visible = False` if the query returns empty.

My Code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strCon);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT url, websiteId FROM Website WHERE name LIKE @search + '%' OR url LIKE @search + '%'", conn);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", search);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);


    if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() != 0)
       {
          ListViewWebsite.DataSource = dt;
          ListViewWebsite.DataBind();
       }
    else if(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 0)
       {
          LabelWebsite.Visible = false;
       }
  conn.Close();
```

The databind works fine if the query returns something.

EDIT: Im aware I run the query multiple times, this code is just a result of testing a bunch of different things. Just posted to give a better idea of what Im trying to achieve

Comment: Do You know that you are executing query 2 times ?

Comment: Yes, Im just testing atm.

Comment: Why do you need `else if`? Why not just simply `else`?

Comment: @CoderofCode 3 times.

Comment: @Steve yep missed that one.

Comment: You only need to use the adapter, or not use the adapter at all and use commands directly.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are filling a `DataTable` you just need to check if it contains rows:

```
LabelWebsite.Visible = dt.Rows.Count > 0;
```

If you used a `DataReader` you could use the  [`HasRows` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
da.Fill(dt);
if(dt.Rows.Count>0)
{

LabelWebsite.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another option if you are really interested to know only if you have rows or not.

```
string cmdText = @"IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Website 
                    WHERE name LIKE @search 
                    OR url LIKE @search) 
                    SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0";
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strCon))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn)
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", search + "%");
    int exists = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    LabelWebsite.Visible = (exists == 1);
}
```

This approach doesn't try to return the rows and its values. It just return 1 if the rows matching the WHERE clause exists or not,

Answer (score 0):

[`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) executes your query and it returns `-1` since your statement is `SELECT` statement.

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. **For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1**

You can check your datatable row count with [`DataRowCollection.Count` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135388%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like;

```
if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    ListViewWebsite.DataSource = dt;
    ListViewWebsite.DataBind();
}
else
{
    LabelWebsite.Visible = false;
}
```

Other than that, use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` rather than calling `.Close()` method manually.

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strCon))
using(SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
   //
}
```

And don't use `AddWithValue` method. It *may* generate unexpected results sometimes. Use `.Add()` method or it's overloads.

- [Can we stop using `AddWithValue()` already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Answer (score 0):

You only need this if you are using a dataadapter :

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strCon);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT url, websiteId FROM Website WHERE name LIKE @search + '%' OR url LIKE @search + '%'", conn);
conn.Open();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", search);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```

Put a breakpoint right after da.Fill and take a look ath the dt variable using the debugger.